# Failed to import a model into a view DJANGO

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, frameworks

Newbie to Django here.

I am trying to import a model into views to use it. However I am facing problems doing so.

First of all, here is the structure of my folder :

[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EgE9.png)

[webpage folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOnqP.png)

When I try to import one of my models into views with:

```
from .models import model_i_want
```

I get :

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

if I try

```
from webpage.models import model_i_want
```

I get :

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'webpage'
```

if I try to import models like this

```
import .models
```

I get this error

```
setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

My webapp is added in the settings, and everything was running smoothly while following the Django official tutorial. I know I should be reading the documentation and figure it out but I can't seem to understand all of it yet and I am still trying to get used to Django.

Thank you and have a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pls check the manage.py file and set the following
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'path to settings file')

Comment: Thank you so much ! I think it resolved the issue. I had the settings for httptest only